# Regex to not include when in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the current RegEx

```
(["'])  \1|([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,\w\/][ ]{2,})
```

I am trying to match

```
var  a = '', b = '';
  something = '';
var something  = 'something i dont know'
    y =  'something'  ,
     1  = 2,
     a =  [
       'something',
        'a'
    ];

function some  () {    
  console.log('someFunction');
}

  function something () {  
      console.log('should allow multiple   Spaces 1!');
      console.log("should allow  multiple Spaces 1!");  
  }
```

I am wanting to make it so it **only** matches double (or more) spaces when it is not within quotes.

It is important that it doesn't complain about spaces at the start of each line (preferably not at the end also)

Comment: You can use the string function .trim() to remove any whitespaces from the beginning and end of the input before testing the input with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
\s{2,}(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX8gI4/1)

Comment: this only matches multiple spaces at the end of the lines

Comment: Try: `\s{2,}(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` The afpha bravo's code has two spaces at the end that should not be there.